# MDX calculations and grouping

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I have a query that returns results for entries that match a calculation of two floating point numbers. IE, when a weighted sum of the two numbers is in a certain range:

```
Select 

    NON EMPTY Measures.AllMembers on 0
from (  
    Select
        Filter(MyDim.[p1].Children * MyDim.[p2].Children, 
               MyDim.[p1].CurrentMember.MemberValue * 0.5 +
           MyDim.[p2].CurrentMember.MemberValue * 0.5 >= 70 
           and
           MyDim.[p1].CurrentMember.MemberValue * 0.5 +
           MyDim.[p2].CurrentMember.MemberValue * 0.5 <= 90)
              on 0 
from MyCube])
```

This query is generated by c# code, and the 0.5's and the 70 and the 90 change.

First off, is there a better way to do this?

Next, how do I create a query that will return ranges of the results with the measures? Something like

```
-----------------------------------------------
< 70       | blah blah blah measures measures
70 - 90    | blah blah blah measures measures 
> 90       | blah blah blah measures measures
-----------------------------------------------
```

If it does this all by itself (ie creates the buckets by magic) that's great, but I wouldn't mind having to find out the possible ranges first, and then writing out the whole query by hand (or code). For now, I can't even work out how to create WITH members or sets or whatever else, rather than having to run individual queries one after another.

Edit: for one parameter, this works if I say

```
WITH
Member MyDim.p1.[<70] as
    Aggregate(Filter(MyDim.p1.members,
        MyDim.p1.CurrentMember.MemberValue < 70))
Member Mydim.p1.[70 - 90] as
    Aggregate(Filter(MyDim.p1.members,
        MyDim.p1.CurrentMember.MemberValue >= 70
        and MyDim.p1.CurrentMember.MemberValue <= 90))
Member MyDim.p1.[>90] as
    Aggregate(Filter(MyDim.p1.members,
        MyDim.p1.CurrentMember.MemberValue> 90))
Select {MyDim.p1.[<70],MyDim.p1.[70 - 90], MyDim.p1.[>90] on 1,
measures.Members on 0
from MyCube
```

This doesn't seem to work for the 2 parameter query.

EDIT: further info
**What do you mean by "parameters"? Values from different hierarchies?** 
Yes, exactly. p1 and p2 in the query above.

**How do you want to determine the buckets? You do not explain the rationale behind the "magic".**
Ideally, it would be broken down into buckets with equal numbers of observations, just like "discretization" does when building a cube - that would be "magic". I'm planning to settle for just taking the min and max values, then breaking the range up into n (say, 10) buckets of size (max - min)/n.

**What do you mean by "does not work"? What did you try and what error messages did you get?**
I'll have to write it again and post the query and the results here - will do in a couple of hours. I think what I tried was the 2nd query, but with p1*p2 in the Filter bit, with the weighted sum in the filter condition. I was trying to put it all into p1 hierarchy. From memory, it ran, but returned all results without filtering anything. I appreciate this is vague, and will update it here. I just thought it was so wholesale wrong, that I didn't bother putting that particular experiment in the original question.

Comment: What do you mean by "parameters"? Values from different hierarchies? How do you want to determine the buckets? You do not explain the rationale behind the "magic". What do you mean by "does not work"? What did you try and what error messages did you get?

Comment: Added answers to the original question